# Problems in using lubridate library

Tags: r, lubridate

I installed the package lubridate.
I got the following:

```
> install.packages("lubridate")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/aw/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/lubridate_1.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 650842 bytes (635 KB)
downloaded 635 KB

package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\aw\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuSQUFy\downloaded_packages
```

and afterwards:

```
> library(lubridate)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringi’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘lubridate’ was built under R version 3.2.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lubridate’
```

Comment: `install.packages("stringi")` - *there is no package called ‘stringi’* is a dead giveaway.

Comment: Relevant good read: [How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)” warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Richard Scriven.
I installed the package stringi:

```
install.packages("stringi")
```

Comment: You could have also done `install.packages("lubridate", dependencies = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

While updating R, it updated all my libraries but it seems if failed at updating **lubridate**. It was complaining that *glue, stringi and stringr* had exit stats of 1. The cmd `install.packages("lubridate")` was building the library and its dependencies from source. However, one of the dependencies was failing as resources were not available in `x64` arch. The solution was to install from binaries:

```
install.packages("glue",type="win.binary")
install.packages("stringi",type="win.binary")
install.packages("stringr",type="win.binary")
install.packages("lubridate",type="win.binary")
```

For mac users, use `mac.binary` instead.

Then I test my lubridate installation by running the following script:

```
library(lubridate)
bday <- dmy("14/10/1979")
month(bday)
#> [1] 10
wday(bday, label = TRUE)
#> [1] Sun
#> Levels: Sun < Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat

year(bday) <- 2016
wday(bday, label = TRUE)
#> [1] Fri
#> Levels: Sun < Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat
```

Kf